# Not able to insmod or use inter-kernel module(s)

Tags: c, kernel, insmod

I have a function in kernel driver 1 (KD1.ko):

```
static void test (void);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(test);

static void test() {
    printk("<<< MISSION DONE >>>.\n");
}
```

In Kernel driver 2 (KD2.ko):

```
extern static void test (void);
```

which I tried to call it.

I managed to insmod KD1.ko, but I was not able to insmod KD2.ko.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test()` is `static`.

so you cannot export static functions.

http://osdir.com/ml/linux.kernel.kernelnewbies/2003-02/msg00149.html

Comment: I was to about to write the same reason :) +1 for that

Comment: I tried removing static, and it still does not work.

Comment: @Babbit what problem exactly you are getting??

Comment: I managed to insmod KD1.ko, but I was not able to insmod KD2.ko.

It states "insmod: error inserting 'KD2.ko': -1 Invalid parameters". 

That never happen before I insert the extern function and tried calling it with just test();

Comment: Plz compare you code with https://github.com/jeyaramvrp/kernel-module-programming/tree/master/depmod-export-sym-demo. You may get some idea.

Comment: Very elegant examples, @Jeyaram.
Examples are the best definitions.