# EXPORT_SYMBOL and the static keyword

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Lets say I have a function hello_world() defined in the file new.c. I create a module out of this file new.c and another file hello.c. This module will be called as new.ko. The function hello_world() is exported using EXPORT_SYMBOL to another module. My question is can I use the static inline keyword while defining the function hello_world() since it is not being used by another function outside the file new.c in the module new.ko?

Do static and EXPORT_SYMBOL contradict each other? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746378/not-able-to-insmod-or-use-inter-kernel-modules/21746424#21746424

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static functions in Linux device driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423333/static-functions-in-linux-device-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they contradict each other. You use `static` to indicate the compiler that you will NOT be calling this function from anywhere outside this file, and `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is used to do just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "export" from Makefile.